# How do I use Switch in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement

I tried to set up background color in SSRS using Switch statement, but it only works haft on what I want to

Here is what I have on a background color for **Software Name**

```
    =Switch(
(Fields!Mainstream_Support_End_Date.Value = "") And (Fields!Extended_Support_End_Date.Value =""),"LightGrey", 
(CDate(Fields!Mainstream_Support_End_Date.Value) > Today()) Or (CDate(Fields!Extended_Support_End_Date.Value) > Today()), "Green"
)
```

I also using the **today** column to check for the code above, here is what I put in the **today** column

```
 =(CDate(Fields!Mainstream_Support_End_Date.Value) > Today() ) Or ( CDate(Fields!Extended_Support_End_Date.Value) > Today() )
```

So I expect if the **Today** is **True** the **Software name** should be **Green**, but it's not
[image]
Did I miss anything?
Thank you,

Comment: You said you had a test expression in the 'Today' column but that is not what is shown in the screenshot. Add columns containing expression to test each part of your switch statement. In theory what you have should work but as you have not yet provided the data from your dataset with the datatypes it's hard to tell what is wrong. Also did you add the additional switch expression as I suggested to test?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment and as I cannot answer directly withotu more info this is just some debugging advice

1. Try reversing the order of the switch expressions so the "Green" test is first (SWITCH stops at the first expression that is true).
2. Add an additional expression/result pair to your SWITCH statement  `True, "Red"` this will catch anything that fails the first two expressions so you can narrow down the issue
3. Add another test column to show the results of the first expression (where you test for empty strings)

If this does not help, post a sample of your dataset including the column/field datatypes as it comes from your dataset query.